# question about API process when reopen the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift, I have trouble resuming my API pulling process on my main page when I reopen the app. When The users didn't log out and close the app, they will be direct to the main page instantly when they reopen my app. But from my console output checking, the whole API pulling process doesn't resume when reopening it. This is my MainPage class:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import AVFoundation

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!

let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // notification create:
    userName.text = "Welcome! \(username ?? "")"
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
                {(granted, error) in
        // action
            }

    center.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { settings in
        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .denied || settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined){
            self.createAlert(title: " Notification required",
            message: "Your current notification is off, please turn it on in settings->IFTTT->Notification")
        }
    })
    getRequest()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// the function that get Request from the API
func getRequest(){
    
    let params: [String:Any] = ["username": username]
    // print(MyVariables.username)
    AF.request("url", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { (response) in
                    do{
                        print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))
                        let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                        var flag: Bool = false
                        var countor: Int = 1
                        // if it has trigger pulling:
                        var info:String = ""
                        // parse JSON
                        while json[String(countor)]["message"].stringValue != ""{
                            print("reached")
                            flag = true
                            info += json[String(countor)]["condition"].stringValue + " message: "
                            info += json[String(countor)]["message"].stringValue
                            if(json[String(countor + 1)]["message"].stringValue != ""){
                                countor += 1
                                info += "\n"
                            } else {
                                break
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                        if(flag){
                            // sound:
                            let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1000
                            // to play sound
                            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
                            // send alert window:
                            self.createAlert(title: " trigger(s) pulled",
                                             message: "You have \(countor) triggers pulled: \n \(info)")
                            // reinitialize flag back to false
                            flag = false
                        }

                    } catch let jsonErr{
                        print(jsonErr)
                    }
                    
                    // Trigger a new request 5s after the response
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: { [weak self] in
                        self?.getRequest()
                    })
                }
}

func createAlert(title: String, message: String){
    let Alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
        Alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

My console keeps sending the output of  `print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))` but after I reopen it, it didn't resume sending it, so I assume it failed to execute getRequest() to loop API pulling after reopening

Can someone please please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your user switches to the springboard (desktop) while your app is running, you will get a few seconds of background time, then get a notice that you are being suspended. (Your app delegate’s `applicationWillResignActive(_:)` method will be called.) At that point you man not get any more processing time, and your app can be terminated at any point after that without any warning. When the user switches back to your app, it might still be in memory, or it might have been terminated. If it is still in memory, it will get a resume event and all your app state will still be around.

Note that you **might** get a `willTerminateNotification` Message instead of a call to `applicationWillResignActive(_:)` in unusual circumstances, but that in recent versions of iOS you **don’t** normally get a `willTerminateNotification`.

If it was terminated you’ll get a cold app start next time the user switches back to your app. There is no automatic mechanism for your app to pick up where it left off in that case. You have to build that yourself.

You should treat the call to `applicationWillResignActive(_:)`  as a “get your affairs in order” chance to save your app state so you can restore it if you get terminated.